# Laravel 4 Eloquent/Model Relationships

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am setting up several Models an want to know the correct approach to table structure and Model relationships.

Let's assume we have a shop containing products, each with properties size and color.

**Table `products`**

- id
- size_id
- color_id
- price

**Table `sizes`**

- id
- name

**Table `colors`**

- id
- name

**Models**

```
class Product extends Eloquent {
    public function size() {
        return $this->hasOne('Size', 'id');
    }
    public function color() {
        return $this->hasOne('Color', 'id');
    }
}
class Size extends Eloquent {
    public function products() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Product', 'size_id');
    }
}
class Color extends Eloquent {
    public function products() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Product', 'color_id');
    }
}
```

This way I can easily echo the color/size of a product using `{{ Product->size['name'] }}`. Also, I want to pass Eloquent the size's foreign key `size.id` like `Product::where('size_id', '5')` rather than its name `size.name`.

**Problem:** Doing `$products = Product::has('size', '=', '5')->get()` does not give me any results, yet doing `$products = Product::where('size_id', '5')->get()` does.

I am pretty confused, what went wrong?

Comment: Do you have your foreign constraints setup properly?

Comment: @RobW I just edited the post, do you mean `$this->belongsTo('Size', 'size_id');`?

Comment: And, don't you mean `$products = Product::has('size', '>=', 5)->paginate(15)`

Comment: @RobW That gave me the error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sizes()`

Comment: Sorry, fixed my comment.

Comment: @RobW I get the same error `Has method invalid on "belongsTo" relations.`

Comment: Try ->hasOne('Size') , etc

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31438/discussion-between-rob-w-and-nyxynyx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the problem is that your `::has()` method is looking for products with exactly 5 different sizes on each specific product, which would assume that you would be using `$this->hasMany('Size')` in your Product model. Where as the `::where()` method is returning results where the size of the product is 5.

In the documentation they use an example of comments. A post will have a list of comments. You can find posts that have at least one comment (ie. `Post::has('comments')->get()`) or you can find posts that have more than 3 comments (ie. `Post::has('comments', '>=', '3')->get()`).

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#querying-relations