# Laravel + Eloquent - Passing through custom function first

Tags: laravel, eloquent

What I want to do is quite simple I think. In my controller I have the code:

```
$list = SiteCategory::where('type','=','A')->get();
```

Which returns a standard eloquent collection object. However, sometimes when I retrieve categories, I want them to be ordered in a specific way first. So can I have some function in my model like:

```
Class SiteCategory extends Eloquent {

    public function mySpecialFunction(){
         // retrieve all categories, manipulate them in some way and return.
    }

}
```

How do I then call this function? I don't understand, and the tutorials and questions I've read do not help. For example, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16995452/laravel-4-eloquent-model-relationships) on SO, he seems to imply he can call his function something like this:

```
SiteCategory->mySpecialFunction()
```

I don't get it?

Comment: why not just sort them after they've been retreived? if the sorting is done via a function, it will always be done after the database fetch either way.

Comment: OK, so if I put this function in my model, then is it possible to chain it onto an eloquent call like siteCategory::All()->mySpecialFunction() Or do I have to declare it as a static function and call it separately?

Comment: This question has an example of using a custom sort function: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15533659/sorting-data-with-eloquent

Comment: Thanks, Stefan, I've actually solved this now. The key was declaring $variable = new SiteCategory() then $variable->mySpecialFunction() in my controller, and accessing eloquent using $this within mySpecialFunction()

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `scope` method inside your `Model` like this

```
Class SiteCategory extends Eloquent {

    public function scopeMySpecialFunction($query){
        // retrieve all categories, manipulate them in some way and return.
    }

}
```

Then you can call this function like normal built in Eloquent functions like

```
SiteCategory::mySpecialFunction();
```

If you want to pass any arguments into this function then you can add parameters like this

```
public function scopeMySpecialFunction($query, $param1, $param2){
    // retrieve all categories, manipulate them in some way and return.
}
```

Notice the first `$query` parameter, it's the first parameter of a scope method and `$query` is an instance of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`, you can use `$this` inside that function and can chain methods like

```
SiteCategory::mySpecialFunction()->find(1);
```

In this case you have to return the `$query` from your function to chain other methods, like:

```
public function scopeMySpecialFunction($query, $param1, $param2){
    // do something
    return $query;
}
```